# Up-to-date solution for cloning commerce product-variation types and their product displays

Tags: commerce

I am using Drupal 7 with commerce module. There are a lot of product-types with a plethora of fields – but in general, only a few fields differ, the vocabularies attached to the product for example. So I would like to stubbornly clone the product-variants and their product-display and make some minor changes manually afterwards. It's important, that the display settings are cloned, too.
While researching, I found a confusing amount of modules that seem to offer that kind of functionality:

- [replicate_commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/replicate_commerce)
- [bundle_copy_commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/bundle_copy_commerce)
- [bundle_inherit](http://drupal.org/project/bundle_inherit)
- [field_tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_tools)
- [features_clone](https://www.drupal.org/project/features_clone)
- https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/davidfiaty/2745827

I would be glad to hear advices from savvy people for modules and appropriate workflows.

Answer (score 1):

After trying out all above modules, I can clearly say for my usecase the winner is:
[bundle_copy](https://www.drupal.org/project/bundle_copy) for cloning product displays in combination with [bundle_copy_commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/bundle_copy_commerce) for the product variations.
Cave: I didn't use the clone/copy feature of both moduls because of errors and poor cloning (fieldgroups weren't copied) – instead I used the export/import feature:

1. Export the entity
2. Replace in the code from step 1 all occurences of the bundle name with a new name
3. Import the code from step 2 again.
4. When using fieldgroups you have to make sure, you rename the fieldgroups in step 4 with a unique name (add the bundle name as a suffix, for example).